# Bootstrap nav Empty white space to right side of page on mobile but only on one particular page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, layout, nav

Most pages on my site look fine on mobile, and (via php include) they all include the same fixed top bootstrap 3 navbar and fixed bottom bootstrap footer. Unfortunately, on [this one page](http://www.bridgewaycc.org/prototype2/blog.php?cat=gregg), which happens to be the blog page, it is almost 3 times wider than all the other pages.  This results in a large white gap on the right side of the page, a horizontal scroll bar and the collapsed hamburger menu for the nav showing up on the far right, out of view.  This only occurs on mobile and only for this page.  As I said, all other pages include the same navbar at top and same footer at the bottom.

In Chrome developer tools, I can see that most of the page elements are 360px in width (e.g. using the Galaxy S5 view) or 375px (the iPhone 6 view), but this element inside the nav is 1036px (iPhone 6 view):

```
<div class="navbar-header">
```

Then again, in the footer, this element is the same 1036px:

```
<div class="row">
```

I cannot figure out what is making these elements stretch to that width, resulting in the blank white space on the right side.

[Here is another page](http://www.bridgewaycc.org/prototype2/newhere.php) using the exact same nav and footer (included dynamically by a php include) where the nav and footer are the proper width and there is no horizontal scrolling and the collapsed hamburger menu is visible in the upper right of the page.

Any ideas why this might be?  Been struggling with this for 2 days now and googling.  Have tried many of the suggestions in Chrome development tools.  The only thing that works is setting a max-width of 375px for @media (max-width: 768px) on that navbar-header div, which to me is unacceptable and would basically mean giving up.  I would like to figure out this puzzle.

Comment: If it only happens on one page and not others, the first line of questioning should be: "What is different about just this page?"  Do you have any special elements here, or custom CSS that applies to this page?

Comment: That's what's puzzling.  That's exactly why I've posted this issue here.  I've compared this page with the pages that are working and there are differences - I have a class for the header of that page, but that's not the element that is too wide.  It's the shared elements (top nav and footer) that are too wide! Now, the purpose of this page being a blog, the content comes dynamically from queries to wordpress, but looking at the content generated by those queries, I don't see anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: I've also noticed that it is only this blog page where the footer does not show fixed at bottom until you scroll down to about 1/2 way through the first blog post.  The rest of the pages, the fixed bottom footer is always visible as it should be.

Comment: Playing around with deleting elements on the page in Chrome development tools inspector, I found out that if I delete all of the dynamically rendered blog content, the nav in the header is correct size.  So, narrowing it down, there is a particular section of one of the blog entry's content wherein 2 links are contained, if I delete both of those links, the problem goes away.  So, I'm thinking there may be something wrong with those links.

Comment: Turns out that if I remove the URL inside the text of the anchor tag and replace it with a normal string (on both of those links), the whole problem goes away.